# Correct way to parse JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the string:

```
'[\'{"cx":3575,"cy":1657,"r":98}\', \'{"cx":3284,"cy":1706,"r":81}\', \'{"cx":4260,"cy":1611,"r":97}\', \'{"cx":3350,"cy":1632,"r":60}\', \'{"cx":3475,"cy":1586,"r":77}\', \'{"cx":4243,"cy":1474,"r":87}\']'
```

How I can get correct array of dicts from this?

Comment: ok, json.loads(str_js.replace("'", "")) works just fine, I spent half an hour trying rid off backslashes.

Comment: The title is misleading.  That isn't a valid JSON string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen why is not valid? I get it from pandas dataframe. Original looks like: ['{"cx":2549,"cy":2329,"r":80}', '{"cx":2437,"cy":2321,"r":74}'] Is it valid?

Comment: No the single quotes are not valid. That’s why you had to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```py
import ast

string = '[\'{"cx":3575,"cy":1657,"r":98}\', \'{"cx":3284,"cy":1706,"r":81}\', \'{"cx":4260,"cy":1611,"r":97}\', \'{"cx":3350,"cy":1632,"r":60}\', \'{"cx":3475,"cy":1586,"r":77}\', \'{"cx":4243,"cy":1474,"r":87}\']'

# Convert string to list
arr = ast.literal_eval(string)

# Convert list of strings to list of dicts
arr = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in arr]
```